# Why python exe is not working for listdir functionality

Tags: python

I created below simple program. It works if i run normally on sublime but when i create a exe using pyinstaller it does not work. It does not give any error it just shows program name and then terminates.

```
import os
from time import sleep

files = os.listdir('C:')

for file in files:
    print(file)


sleep(5)
```

Comment: Put a full pathname in the argument to `os.listdir()`

Comment: It is full path only. I want to list all the files/dir in c drive.

Comment: It only lists one directory, it doesn't recurse. Try `C:/` to list the root of the C drive.